# Sorting items after building an XML feed?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working in a CMS (Modern Campus) that is XML-based. XSLT is still a thing i'm attempting to learn on the fly, so I am not well-versed in this area yet.

Our CMS is building a blog feed (which we use for news) using the following code:

```
        <items>
        <!--Internal News Articles-->
        <xsl:for-each select="$internal-doc/items/item">
            <xsl:sort select="concat(substring(pubDate,7,4), substring(pubDate,1,2),substring(pubDate,4,2))" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(articlePreview) or articlePreview != 'true'">
                <item>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute()|node()" />
                    <searchtags>{string-join(tags/tag, ',')}</searchtags>
                </item>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>     
        <!--External News Articles-->
        <xsl:if test="$include-broadcast='true'"> <!--Check to see if broadcast option is on, if so, get external news articles-->
            <xsl:for-each select="$array">
            <xsl:variable name="external-doc" select="(.)" /> <!--Get current array item-->
            <xsl:variable name="base-url" select="tokenize($external-doc, '/_resources')[1]" /> <!--Get website URL, need to use it for link to news and images-->
            <xsl:for-each select="$external-doc/document(.)/items/item">
                <xsl:sort select="concat(substring(pubDate,7,4), substring(pubDate,1,2),substring(pubDate,4,2))" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="contains(broadcast,$broadcast-unit)">
                    <item>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href" select="concat($base-url,@href)"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute()[not(name() = 'href')]|node()[not(name() = 'hero-image') and not(name() = 'image')]" /> 
                        <xsl:if test="image">
                            <image>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="not(contains(image/img/@src,'://'))">
                                        <img>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="src" select="concat($base-url,image/img/@src)"/>
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="image/img/attribute()[not(name() = 'src')]" />
                                        </img>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:apply-templates select="image/img" /></xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </image>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <searchtags>{string-join(tags/tag, ',')}</searchtags>
                    </item> 
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </items>
```

The code works great - the second half of the code looks at an external blog feed to see if it needs to bring in any items from it. This code works as well. The issue I'm having, or unsure of how to accomplish, is performing a final sort based on the pubDate. As it currently stands, when the feed is built, the internal news articles are sorted, and then when the external news articles are added, they too are sorted, but both are sorted separately. What I want is a final sort so that if an external news article happens to have a newer date than an internal news article, it will appear at the top of the feed, not at the end of the feed, as the code will presently do. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is that XSLT 3 you are using or why do you seem to have `<searchtags>{string-join(tags/tag, ',')}</searchtags>` text value templates? Anyway, you can certainly do something like a single `<xsl:for-each select="$internal-doc/items/item, $array ! document(.)/items/item"><xsl:sort select="concat(substring(pubDate,7,4), substring(pubDate,1,2),substring(pubDate,4,2))" order="descending"/>`. If you want to use your existing two `for-each`s outputting something to sort/merge later, you would need to use a variable (and of course make sure the pubDate or sort key is also output.

Comment: The .xsl file that this is in DOES say <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0">, yes. I did not write that portion of the code, it was included as part of our CMS install.
I think you lost me on the code you provided.

Comment: Yes, good to know the version, unusual for most people showing up here that are stuck with XSLT 1.0, but with XSLT 3 you have a lot of options and expressive power so use that.